# Hibernate Envers claims EntityManager is closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have a Spring (Boot) application on which I'm trying to use Hibernate Envers.

The following `bar` function throws an `IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed`, while the `foo` function works flawlessly:

```
@Service
public class FoobarService {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public FoobarService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Iterable<Foobar> foo() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select f from Foobar f", Foobar.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Iterable<Foobar> bar() {
        System.out.println(entityManager.isOpen()); // <--- Returns true!

        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        AuditQueryCreator queryCreator = auditReader.createQuery();
        AuditQuery query = queryCreator.forRevisionsOfEntity(Foobar.class, true);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Does anybody know why it claims it's closed when the `foo` function clearly works (as stated above)?

PS: I've omitted the maven dependencies and entity mapping for brevity, as they're all working.

**EDIT:**

There's something really weird I can't figure out. Within the `bar` function, we can see that:

1. `entityManager.isOpen()` returns true
2. `((Session) entityManager.getDelegate()).isOpen()` returns false

The `AuditReaderFactory.get(EntityManager entityManager)` function uses the second, this is why it complains the session is closed when it's not. I don't quite get why the `delegate` is closed, so:

1. Why does the the factory uses the `entityManager`'s delegate instead?
2. Why the delegate is even closed?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858463/3881354

Comment: I was thinking of creating a Configuration for Hibernate Envers indeed, however this approach is the same as injecting an `PersistenceContext` (EntityManager) of type `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`. In other words, both approaches return an application-managed `EntityManager`, on which should be avoided, am I right?

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh the answer you linked is wrong. Mine is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70177753/554117

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same issue, when running a `@SpringBootTest` I needed to get a hold of `EntityManager` like they showed in the Envers user-guide.

If you go to Hibernate Envers [github-project tests](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/b82d4c3c74c88af484ac22924e89e7a797d430f3/hibernate-envers/src/test/java/org/hibernate/orm/test/envers/BaseEnversJPAFunctionalTestCase.java#L271), you can see that they use the factory to get the `EntityManager`.

I tried to annotate my `EntityManager` in the test with either `@Autowire` or `@PersistenceContext`, in both cases `EntityManager` object was opened but the delegate was closed like in your case.
It only worked when I autowired the factory:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

And then created an entityManager for my test like this:

```
var entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```