# Why AuditReader can't be Autowired in the Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

IN my springbootapp I have the following repository:-

```
@Repository
public class RevisionRepository {

private AuditReader auditReader;

public RevisionRepository(AuditReader auditReader) {
    this.auditReader = auditReader;
  }
}
```

When I run this app. I got this error:-

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-12-24 21:09:15 -

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.howtodoinjava.demo.repository.RevisionRepository required a bean of type 'org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader' in your configuration.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Put @Autowired on private AuditReader auditReader;

Comment: You should create AuditReader bean manually. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858463/14503270)

Comment: @kmplzz thx for the suggestion. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my issue. Hopefully, it will be helpful for others:-

```
@Configuration
public class RevisionConfiguration {

@Autowired
private AuditReader auditReader;

private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public RevisionConfiguration(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
AuditReader auditReader() {
    return AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager());
  }
}
```

Comment: see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/70012134/554117

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer didn't work for me because, after some time the application is running, it starts throwing java.net.SocketException due to connection closed.

I solved the issue by:

1. Wiring EntityManager using @PersistenceContext
2. Getting a new instance of AuditReader each time

   ```
   public class AuditRepository {

   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   private AuditReader getAuditReader() {
       return AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
   }

   public Optional<T> getRevision() {
       final AuditReader auditReader = getAuditReader();
       ...
   }
   ```